Can I plug speakers into the XLR and TRS jacks on my mixer, at the same time?
I have a left and right channel, both of these have a XLR and TRS connector.  This is a Mackie Onyx.
In such setups am I supposed to be able to hook multiple sets of speakers (in my case 4 total speakers) at the same time, or are they intended to be simply one output per channel (R/L) with an option on how to connect?

My Mackie mixer has two output channels (L & R) and four output jacks,  two XLRs (LR) and two 1/4 inch (LR).  These output jacks can be used in any combination.  I sometimes use the XLRs to send signals to the main front PA speakers and the 1/4" to monitors. All four outputs are line out signals that may be connected to any device that will receive a line-level signal.  I sometimes just use the 1/4" outputs with unbalanced cables and other times only the XLR outputs that are balanced.  I have never found any difference between the XLRs and 1/4" output signals and have had no problem using 1 or more of the outputs in any combination.

Yes, you can use both outputs on each channel into two pairs of powered speakers.  You won't have individual volume controls for each pair of speakers though.
There are several 'Onyx' models in Mackie's catalogue.  Maybe yours also offers alternative, more controllable outputs.  Perhaps the Ctrl Room outputs?

Thank you for this answer, accepted the other one just because it was a little more detailed but this was also helpful.

@Ken-EnoughaboutMonica Actually my answer contained more information.  The one you chose said just one thing - yes, you can use both outputs - at great length.   Mine said that succinctly, and also offered an alternative way of connecting two pairs.   But I'm not bitter about it!
